# uPython for Node MCU and L293D Motor Shield

Tags: nodemcu, micropython

I am trying to use the  L293D Motor Shield for Node MCU, controlling it with micropython. I've only found one code example for micropython, and it does not appear to work. Does anyone have any code examples I can start with (that works)?

Can you tell why my code example does not function as expected? Should I conclude the the problem is that my motor shield is dead/defective?

I've connected everything and checked that the wire connections are ok, and that the motor works. I've uploaded my code and it runs without errors.

```py
from machine import Pin, PWM
import time
print("hello")

""" nodemcu pins from the motor shield """
pin1 = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)  # D1
pin2 = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)  # D2
pin3 = Pin(0, Pin.OUT)  # D3
pin4 = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)  # D4

""" named after the L9110 h-bridge pins """
BIN1 = PWM(pin1, freq=750)
BIN2 = PWM(pin3, freq=750)
AIN1 = PWM(pin2, freq=750)
AIN2 = PWM(pin4, freq=750)

""" TODO: variable speed """
speed = 950 

def stop_all():
    for each in (BIN1, BIN2, AIN1, AIN2):
        each.duty(0)

def forward():
    BIN1.duty(speed)
    BIN2.duty(speed)
    AIN1.duty(speed)
    AIN2.duty(speed)
    print("inside forward")

forward()
time.sleep(5)
stop_all()
```

It's just stone dead. No voltage on the output of the motor shield (with our without the motor connected) and not even the slightest hum from the motor.

Comment: does it print "inside forward" ?

Comment: Have you checked the voltages on the GPIO pins driving the motor shield? I would start as simple as possible by leaving out the PWM and just confirming that you are turning the correct pins on or off. Also if [this](https://my.cytron.io/p-l293d-shield-for-nodemcu-v2?r=1) is your shield, it looks as if you're currently applying a PWM signal to the direction as well as the speed inputs? Presumably the direction should be constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I have officially given this up now. I experimented with it this evening and managed to fry two PWM's with my 12 volt battery. In both cases, I am positive I connected it to the motor power supply and with the right polarity and in both cases it just fried the board - with smoke and a small flame and everything. It died quite dramatically. Now I am out of PWM's but I do have an arduino motor shield. I think I'll try with that in stead. The documentation is sooo much better.

Comment: things don't die in smoke and flames if you wire things correctly... also how can you fry a Pulse Width Modulation? that's not a hardware term. maybe you supplied the logic Vcc with 12V?

Comment: If you were driving a 'raw' H-bridge it would be possible to short out the motor supply by turning on the wrong combination of outputs, and that probably would result in smoke and flames. If I'm looking at the right NodeMCU shield though, it has 'speed' and 'direction' inputs so should have its own logic to stop that happening. In that case incorrect connection is about the only explanation left for frying anything.